# Parse line for specific date format?

Tags: bash, parsing, scripting

Writing a script using bash. I am trying to look through lines in a file for a specific date format:

```
date +"%a %b %d %T %Z %Y"
```

For example, if the line were

```
/foo/bar/foobar this 12 is 411 arbitrary stuff in the line Wed Jun 10 10:10:10 PST 2017
```

I would want to obtain Wed Jun 10 10:10:10 PST 2017.

Any way to search for specific date formats?

Comment: Could line contain multiple date substrings?

Comment: It would only contain one date. Functionally, the script will only check the first and last lines of the file as where this will be the only place relevant dates will be. However, I phrased the question to be a little more open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you'll agree with this approach. But if this is for some quick, non-recurring work, I won't look for a perfect solution that can handle all the scenarios.

To start with, you can use the following too generic pattern to match the part you want.

```
cat file | sed -n 's/.*\(... ... .. ..:..:.. ... ....\).*/\1/p'
```

Then you can enhance this further restricting the matches as you need.

E.g.

```
cat file | sed -n 's/.*\([a-Z]\{3\} [a-Z]\{3\} [0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [A-Z]\{3\} [0-9]\{4\}\).*/\1/p'
```

Note that this still is not perfect and can match invalid contents. If you find it still not good enough, you can further fine tune the pattern to the point you want.